# Maven multiple profile cannot resolve symbol

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

My application structure is

- profile (application project)

  +--- service (module)
   
    +--- oracle repository (module)
   
    +--- mysql repository (module)

As a service module I implemented Maven profile activation with multiple conditions (ex. staging pickup oracle repository, cloud pickup mysql repository) as below code.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>staging-local</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>staging-local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.platform.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>repositories</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>staging</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.platform.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>repositories</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>production</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.platform.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>repositories</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>cloud</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>cloud</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.platform.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>repositories-mysql-cloud</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>cloud-local</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>cloud-local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.platform.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>repositories-mysql-cloud</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
```

Everything is fine but I got error on IntelliJ Editor

> cannot resolve symbol '{Class in repository module}'

[image]

If I manually add the repository module it's fixed but I don't want to do this.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.platform.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>repositories</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

as the image above I show you the Maven project in each module.

You can see the Service module has a repository module (look at the highlight line).

Profile application has a Service module **but in service module it does not have a repository module** that it's a root cause of this.

**Summary**
Only dependencies in maven multiple profile not load to profile project.

Anyone Can help me? How to fix it?

Comment: Do you see that dependency in "Project Structure | Modules | <Module Name> | Dependencies"? Also please try to run "File | Invalidate Caches" and "Refresh" from Maven tool window.

Comment: The dependencies in profile only works in compile phase,and don't take participate in transitivity,you could add the profile in `service` module to application project,or add to a parent pom that both service and application inherit

Comment: @y.bedrov, Thank for your reply but it still not fix.

Comment: @neo, Thank for your reply. the profile is application project. It's impossible to fix this right?

Comment: I mean  maven profile , not your profile project